# How to create infinite loop slider using offset in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am working on this project and I made a slider that slides 3 pics at a time but when it comes to the last 3 pics  it stops (because of the condition) but I want to make it into infinite loop and I want it to autoslide every 3 seconds. Does anybody know how I can rewrite this part of code to make this work?

```js
const carousel = document.querySelector(".carouselSlides");
const card = carousel.querySelector(".card");
const leftButton = document.querySelector(".slideLeft");
const rightButton = document.querySelector(".slideRight");


const carouselWidth = carousel.offsetWidth;
const cardStyle = card.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(card);
const cardMarginRight = Number(cardStyle.marginRight.match(/\d+/g)[0]);

const cardCount = carousel.querySelectorAll(".card").length;

let offset = 0;
const maxX = -(
  (cardCount / 3) * carouselWidth +
  cardMarginRight * (cardCount / 3) -
  carouselWidth -
  cardMarginRight
);

leftButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (offset !== 0) {
    offset += carouselWidth + cardMarginRight;
    carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${offset}px)`;
  }
});

rightButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (offset !== maxX) {
    offset -= carouselWidth + cardMarginRight;
    carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${offset}px)`;
  }
});
```

```css
.carouselContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 58vh;
  width: 92vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carouselSlides {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.button-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.slideLeft {
  position: relative;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 4rem;
  right: 26rem;
}

.slideRight {
  position: relative;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 4rem;
  left: 26rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="carouselContainer">
  <div class="carouselSlides">
    <div id="slide0" class="card">
      <div class="card__thumbnail">
        <span class="card__title">FADE</span>
        <button class="morebtn" onclick="">READ MORE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <button class="slideLeft">&#8249;</button>
    <button class="slideRight">&#8250;</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Where are the pictures? Please complete the code.

Comment: Pictures are generated through this function                                             function cloningCards(agentNamesSlide) {
  for (let i = 0; i < agentNamesSlide.length; i++) {
    var clone = slide.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = `slide${i + 1}`;
    clone.getElementsByClassName(
      "card__title"
    )[0].innerHTML = `${agentNamesSlide[i]}`;
    slide.after(clone);
  }
}